# Question on why these two derivatives are equal

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $\;f:U\to \mathbb R^m\;$ where $\;U\subset \mathbb R^n$ and
>   consider its gradient matrix $\;Df=(f^j_{x_i})_{1 \le i \le n, 1\le j
>  \le m}\;$ (i.e $\;f^j_{x_i}=\frac{\partial f^j}{\partial x_i}\;$) If
>   $\;\vert \cdot \vert \;$ is the Frobenius norm of the matrix then
>   show:
>
> $\;(\frac{1}{2} {\vert Df \vert}^2)_{x_\beta}=\sum_{\alpha =1}^n
>  f^k_{x_\alpha} f^k_{x_\alpha x_\beta}\;$ for $\;\beta
>  =1,\dots,n\;\;,\;k=1,\dots,m\;$

**My Attempt:**

As I understand it, since $\;\frac{1}{2} {\vert Df \vert}^2=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n {\vert f^j_{x_i} \vert}^2\;$ then $\;(\frac{1}{2} {\vert Df \vert}^2)_{x_\beta}=\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n f^j_{x_i} f^j_{x_i x_\beta}\;$ which is quite close to the one above except for the additional sum on $\;j\;$. Is there any way for these two to be equal?

I would appreciate any help.Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense that $k$ is a free index on the right hand side of the given answer. The Frobenius norm is a scalar and its derivative should be a scalar. Perhaps the given answer is missing a summation over $k$?

Comment: @PaulAljabar I think the same too. I'll check once more if I'm missing something on the given info